# VAR evaluation in Makefile

Tags: python, bash, makefile

I want that `make wheel` print the wheel name

```
cat Makefile
wheel:
    @rm -fr build dist
    @python setup.py bdist_wheel
    $(eval WHEEL=$(shell find . -name '*.whl'))
    @printf '\n => wheel ready %s\n\n' $(WHEEL)
```

This *almost* work, effectively because eval is evaluated BEFORE the call to setup.py the `dist` folder is empty.

I've tryed with `WHEEL:=$(shell find . -name '*.whl')` too, same result

Comment: Putting `@` before every command is an antipattern. Run with `make -s` if you don't want to see commands printed.

Comment: If you need `find` to locate your wheel file after it is created, your build process needs to be fixed.

Comment: Unless you set `.ONESHELL:` as a pseudo-target, each line in a recipe is executed separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the results in a variable seems completely misdirected.

```
wheel:
    @rm -fr build dist
    python setup.py bdist_wheel
    @printf '\n => wheel ready %s\n\n' $$(find . -name '*.whl')
```

The `printf` newlines look wacky but maybe you like spurious empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different target to create the files. Store the command in a variable with `$(shell)` (you're using GNU Make, right?), using it will run the associated command:

```
WHEEL = $(shell find . -name '*.whl')

wheel: create_wheel
    printf '\n => wheel ready %s\n\n' $(WHEEL)

create_wheel:
    @rm -fr build dist
    @python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

You need to use `=` when assigning the command, otherwise (with `:=`) it will be evaluated at the beginning of the make process.